# execute objective-c method on document load

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, call

Pretty confused newbie here:

I have a class, this class is adding columns to a table. In a first step this was done by hitting a button. I've added a generic object to the interface builder, assigned the class that adds the column to the table and made the connections; this way when I hit the button the columns are added. Now I need to modify this program and run the method whenever a document is loaded (document based application), so I need to call my method from inside the `- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController` method. Now what confuses me is: how can I call a method of an object that is connected to the interface builder?

--- EDIT ---

If you feel you have to downvote, please at least say why! since I am a newbie what may sound like a stupid question for you is a pretty advanced question for me.

--- EDIT 2 ---

Probelm found, check my own answer.

Comment: What's an "Xcode method"?

Comment: a method, inside a class, used in xcode.. why the downvote?!?! as said i am a beginner..

Comment: XCode is not a language. It's a development environment. You're probably getting down votes because you did not include any code.

Comment: thanks for clarifying.. i edited the title. as for the code, there is not much code i could post.. its a more generic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem is: my class adds column to the table by reading out informations from a NSarraycontroller. this NSArraycontroller is populated by the coreframework. but it is populated only AFTER the view is loaded so i cannot fill the tables at startup without using a timer or something like that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an outlet. 
Control drag from IB (Interface Builder) to the View Controller.

Comment: thanks! but it doesnt seem to work.. my situation is this: i have a class, in the interface builder tehre is a NSobject that has its class set to the class i have made. this object is connected to the NSButton (IBAction) and to the NSTableview (IBOutlet). i want to delete the button, and execute the method present in my class from inside my document.m file. i tried to control drag it but i do not get any option. thanks for your help!